# Delete tab in dataframe with Bash

Tags: bash

I have this data frame, in the last column there is a tab (denote with "_", this line doesn't exist):

```
ATO98108  AVP78042   0.1371      1.4224      0.0964      0.29731     SARSr-bat-CoV   SARSr-bat-CoV_     
ATO98120  AVP78042   0.1376      1.2989      0.1060      0.29281     SARSr-bat-CoV   SARSr-bat-CoV_
```

I´m using Bash to delete all this tabs with something like this:

```
sed 's/ //g'
```

However, this line only works with the beginning of the line not the end.
How I can do it to delete the space blank at the end of the line?

Comment: That should remove all spaces anywhere in the line. If it's not removing the last character, it's not really a space.

Comment: `s/ //g` should be removing *all* spaces, not just an initial space. Use `s/ $//g`.

Comment: (Actually, the `g` is unnecessary, as there can be only *one* line-final space. If you want to remove *all* trailing spaces, something like `s/ *$//`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, this option keeps the final space. I'm using this line (with yours advices): `sed 's/ *$//' S_OmeTaj.tsv | less > Test.csv` What is wrong? @chepner

Comment: See Barmar's comment. I can't reproduce.

Comment: It's a "tab", is it possible to delete it all with something like the line you share? @chepner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final "space" in each line turned out to be a space followed by a tab. To remove both, use

```
sed 's/[\t ]*$//' yourFile
```

If you want to overwrite the file, use `sed -i ...`

Comment: Thank for an answer, I tried your option but I don´t understand why doesn't work. Here is my example data: [link] (https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_dataframe_delete_tab), could you try to solve the problem? Only to see if you can solve. @Socowi

Comment: @Mauri1313 Thanks for the actual file. I adapted the answer.